# final method / class with testing

Tags: java, testing, final

given the very simple example:

```
public MyClass {

    final List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void method1() {
        ...
        addToNumbers(100);
        ...
    }

    boolean addToNumbers( Integer elem) {
        return numbers.add(elem);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public MyClassTest() {

    @Test
    private void method1Test() {
        final MyClass x = new MyClass();
        ...
        //some mocking
        ...
        x.addToNumbers();
        ...
    }
}
```

If no inheritance is involved, does it make sense to declare the method addToNumbers() final? What about the test class? Does it make sense to declare it final as well?

Comment: just because there is no inheritance involved, doesn't mean there won't be in the future. do you want someone to be able to change the functionality of addToNumbers?

Comment: You can make them final if you want. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: Only use `final` if you have a good reason, having classes open for extension is a Good Thing. Also, if you do TDD and want to use mocks you'll be happy if classes and methods aren't final.

Comment: I know final means "don't touch this" but someone might change it in the future. Change is the only constant. Nothing stops a fellow developer to just delete the final keyword, change the code and commit the code